# Почему не работает итерация по циклу? JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

```
function change (array) {
    sum_x = array[0];
    sum_y = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (sum_x > sum_y * 2) {
            sum_y += array[i];
        } else if (sum_y > sum_x * 2) {
            sum_x += array[i];
        }
        return [sum_x, sum_y]
    }
}
```

Вызов функции:

```
change([13, 2, 8, 17, 22, 13, 25, 98, 42, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 13, 18, 22, 24])
```

Ответ выдает:

```
[ 13, 10 ]
```

Comment: В коде есть ошибка в условии цикла for. Вместо 1 < array.length должно быть i < array.length

Comment: @VladimirGlinskikh
после изменения цикл всё равно зависает, только теперь на 2 итерации, а не на 1

Comment: `return [sum_x, sum_y]` внутри цикла - это значит что выполнится только первая итерация